# FileNotFoundError but the file is in the directory

Tags: python

So when I'm trying to concatenate several Excel files into a single df, it shows me this:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Agosto_2019.xlsx'`

I don't understand why, since the file is in the directory. My code so far has been

---

```
files = [file for file in os.listdir('.\meses_31')]


mes_31 = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    año = file.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]
    mes = file.split('.')[0].split('_')[0]
    name = file
    print(name)
    df = pd.read_excel(name, skiprows = 14)
    df = df.loc[:, df.columns.notnull()]
    df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed', na=False)]
    df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^None', na=False)]
    df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('RESUMEN MES', na=False)]
    df['año']= año
    df['mes']= mes
    mes_31 = pd.concat([mes_31, df_], sort=False)
mes_31.head()
```

---

Some names are in Spanish, but that's not relevant. Mes translates as month, and año as year. One of the thing I want to do is to create a new row that indicates the year and the month.

Comment: your files array wil contain name of file inside 'meses_31' folder while `read_excel` will look that file in current folder.Use something like `pd.read_excel('.\meses_31\'+name, skiprows = 14)`

Comment: Beside the point, but if you're putting backslashes in a string, it's best practice to use a raw string, i.e. `r'.\meses_31'`.

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice. I changed the title of your question to more accurately reflect the problem you're experiencing - hope it helps. In the future it will help you to make a [mre] with minimal code and the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir()` lists files without the directory name, hence you get `'Agosto_2019.xlsx'` instead of `'.\\meses_31\\Agosto_2019.xlsx'`, so `pd.read_excel` tries to open that file in the current directory, but it doesn't exist.

Probably the best way to handle this is to change the working directory with [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir).

```
os.chdir('meses_31')
files = os.listdir('.')  # List comprehension not needed

for file in files:
    ...
    pd.read_excel(file, ...)
    ...
```